# Power series with cubic factorials

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, bessel-functions

I am looking for a starting point to obtain the closed form of
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k \frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^3}. $$
I have tried transforming the ratio of factorials into combinations, but this lead me nowhere. I also computed several values of the series on Wolfram and I expect the answer to look like $e^{2x} I_0(2x)$ for $I_0$ the $0$-th modified Bessel function.
Does anyone has an idea on how to properly obtain the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}x^{k}\,
{\pars{2k}! \over \pars{k!}^{3}}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{x^{k} \over k!}{2k \choose k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{x^{k} \over k!}\bracks{z^{k}}
\pars{1 + z}^{2k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{\bracks{{\pars{1 + z}^{2}x/z}}^{k} \over k!}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}
\exp\pars{{\pars{1 + z}^{2}\,x \over z}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{0}}
\exp\pars{x\,\bracks{{1 \over z} + 2 + z}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\expo{2x}\bracks{z^{0}}
\exp\pars{{1 \over 2}\bracks{\color{red}{2x}}\,\bracks{z + z^{-1}}}
\end{align}

The last exponential in the right hand side is the
[Beseel $\ds{\on{I}_{\nu}}$ Generating Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.35.E1). Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}x^{k}\,
{\pars{2k}! \over \pars{k!}^{3}}} =
\bbx{\expo{2x}\on{I}_{0}\pars{2x}} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct formula for the exponential generating function of the central binomial coefficients $\binom{2k}{k}$.  See https://oeis.org/A000984

Comment: But it says $(k!)^{3}$ in the denominator, not $(k!)^{2}$.

Comment: @LPenguin that's why it is the *exponential* generating function instead of the *ordinary* generating function.

Answer (score 1):

**CONJECTURE:**
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\frac{(2k)!}{k!^3}=e^{2x}I_0(2x)$$
Here's my attempt at showing this using a Cauchy product -

The power series for $e^{2x}$ is:
$$e^{2x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$$
And a [well known expansion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) for $I_0$ is
$$I_0(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2k}}{4^k k!^2}$$
So then
$$I_0(2x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{k!^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k$$

Here we have
$$b_k=\frac{1+(-1)^{k}}{2}\frac{1}{(k/2)!^2}$$

Then, the [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) gives
$$e^{2x}I_0(2x)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k$$

$$c_k=\sum_{j=0}^k a_jb_{k-j}=\sum_{j=0}^k b_ja_{k-j}$$
$$=\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{1+(-1)^{n-j}}{2}\frac{1}{((n-j)/2)!^2}\frac{2^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1+(-1)^{j}}{2}\frac{1}{(j/2)!^2}\frac{2^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}$$
I suppose all there is left to do now is show the above are equal to $(2k)!/k!^3$. (sum experts, help!) This is confirmed by Mathematica.

[image: sum]

And of course the [half integer Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Integers_and_half-integers) is well known. We then have
$$=\frac{4^k(2k)!\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\pi}4^k k!(k!)^2}=\frac{(2k)!}{k!^3}$$
However I think I'm a bit out of my depth to show this using "pencil and paper" methods.